# Django strange error turns my template name into 0x000000000461A128

Tags: python, django

I know I goofed bad because google returned no results. I'm don't know much about computers, but `0x00000blah` looks like some memory address. And after a few refreshes, that number changes.

**Environment** Django 1.8, Python 3.4, chrome, Win7

**Expected behavior**
I want to go to `../accounts/login/` also known as in my urls `url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='loginHandle')` Enter in username, password, if it is registered it redirects to `../accounts/profile` where it SHOULD render the template profile.html which would say something like `Hello {{ username }} !`. INSTEAD I get this ERROR

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/profile/
>
> django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x0000000004D0E400

**views.py**

```
def profile(request):
    profileTemplate = loader.get_template('registration/profile.html')
    return render(request, profileTemplate, {
        'Kitty': 10,
    })
```

**Traceback**

```
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
D:\users\kitty\python\firstdjangosite\templates\<django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x0000000004D0E400> (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
D:\Users\kitty\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\<django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x0000000004D0E400> (File does not exist)
D:\Users\kitty\Python\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\<django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x0000000004D0E400> (File does not exist)
D:\users\kitty\python\firstdjangosite\polls\templates\<django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x0000000004D0E400> (File does not exist)
D:\users\kitty\python\firstdjangosite\login\templates\<django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x0000000004D0E400> (File does not exist)
D:\users\kitty\python\firstdjangosite\accounts\templates\<django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x0000000004D0E400> (File does not exist)
```

**Path Details**

```
D:\Users\Kitty\Python\FirstDjangoSite\accounts\templates>dir /s /b /o:gn
accounts
registration
accounts\index.html
accounts\invalid.html
accounts\loggedin.html
accounts\logout.html
registration\login.html
registration\profile.html
```

I have done loaders and renders before and they work fine. For instance, if I change the profileTemplate to the nonexistent 'registration/helloworld.html' it says

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/profile/
>
> registration/helloworld.html

Thanks for your time, please help I'm ba-baffled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut takes the template name.

```
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'registration/profile.html', {
        'Kitty': 10,
    })
```

The surprising error message is because you have passed a loaded template instead of the template name. The `django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x0000000004D0E400` is the `repr()` of `profileTemplate`.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response, that makes sense and works! Cheers (will accept when SO allows it)